# Preventing glasses from fogging up when wearing scarf

Tags: clothing, eyeglasses, temperature

Wearing a scarf, ski mask, or neck warmer over your nose in winter helps to keep you warm!  The problem is that if you wear eyeglasses, the moment you exhale, all of that moisture seems to all end up on your lenses, eliminating your ability to see.

Is there any way to keep the glasses from fogging up while covering up to stay warm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a few swipes/dabs of white bar soap on each glass and and buff till clear. It will give some pretty good results. It's not possible to completely remove fogging in cold weather due to the law of physics, but this does a great job and is one of the better options as well as inexpensive.

Don't use the heavily scented or colored soaps which will be counterproductive. Something like the white Johnson's baby soap should work well.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if it will work while wearing a scarf, but I use Rain-X on my glasses to help when moving between temperatures to help with fogging.

Comment: As a motorcyclist I used to wipe the inside of my visor with a little washing up liquid on a tissue once a month or so which did the trick. Some scuba divers spit in their masks before a dive which works but doesn't last as well.

Comment: Any idea if Rain-X is safe to use that close to your eyes?

Comment: I only apply it a few times a year, but I haven't noticed an issue...But I think this could potentially be one of those "Your results may vary" things...

Answer (score -1):

[Barracuda defogger](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0024GHXWG)

There are other similar products.