# How can I keep glasses free of fogging from my breath, when wearing ski mask in cold weather?

Tags: eyeglasses

How can I keep glasses free of fogging from my breath, when wearing ski mask in cold weather?

The problem is that, when breathing out, the hot wet breath gets channeled by the mask upwards - both around the sides of the nose inside the mask; and along the mask surface on the outside; and both paths meet cold glasses resulting in immediate fogging when the water from the breath condenses on the cold surface.

## Constraints:

- The glasses are NOT optional - neither taking them off completely, nor wearing contacts, is possible.
- Also, buying special glasses that look like shop safety glasses or swimming goggles, is not an option for the same reason - they don't come in correct prescription and thus are as unfeasible as going without glasses in the first place.
- Covering my glasses in some *chemical is something my optometrist strongly advised against*. As such, my question is different from [this question](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/10576/preventing-glasses-from-fogging-up-when-wearing-scarf), which seems to be concentrated around treating your glasses with some fog-prevention solution.
- To clarify, "not using a mask" isn't a desired solution either. The whole point is to wear a mouth/nose covering mask!

<sub>I apologize if the term ski mask is an in-accurate one, since mos ski masks cover upper part of the face and mine doesn't - it's kind of a cross between a ski mask and motorcycle face mask. Here's kind of what it looks like:</sub>

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preventing glasses from fogging up when wearing scarf](http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/10576/preventing-glasses-from-fogging-up-when-wearing-scarf)

Comment: @JustDoIt - the 3rd bullet links to just that quetsion and explains in detail WHY it's not a duplicate.

Comment: it was my bad, i wanted to mark that one as a dupe of this one, I alt+tab too quickly

Comment: @JustDoIt - Gotcha. I'm not sure that one is a dupe of this either, but I can see your point

Comment: this one has a far more better solution for the *fogging* issue, other ones are basically go and buy something, rather than actual lifehack

Comment: I am not sure if it is a good idea to make new questions out of old ones by just adding more constraints

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From cycling experience (read: significant breathing activity and wind. And once standing at traffic lights, the wind which usually blows away the wet breath is gone and glasses tend to fog immediately). I didn't find a way to keep the nose covered. i.e. use a ski mask designed to cover mouth and nose which is a bit generous in the size of the eye whole and pull the lower rim under your nose. Otherwise you'll always have small gaps next to your nose which perfectly channel the air upwards.

Second ingredient is train to breath in the right direction. Sounds pretty dull, and is annyoing in the beginning, sorry for that. Anyway, depending on what your "neutral jaw position" is (assuming mouth breathing) your exhaust air goes horizontally or slightly upwards or slightly downwards. Try to find a comfortable new neutral position, slightly more opened, the jaw slightly more back and you don't fog your glasses. (really really not much, just a slightly different neutral position. No force, nothing uncomfortable. The annoying thing is that it takes concentration in the beginning because a single breath in upwards and your glasses are white).

Leaving the field of ski masks, these stiff neoprene face masks for mountainbiking ([these](http://img.dxcdn.com/productimages/sku_384027_1.jpg) were the first i found on google) are worth considering. Also worn lower than intended by the manufacturer! I use them as a "stiff scarf" protecting the lower face from wind, due to its stiffness it cannot slip down even if you move your head in all directions. Eventually I switched to those and keep the skimask for really really cold days. Crucial aspect: not the neutral looking soft ones which are sold for winter cycling, but the stiff ones with drawings to look badass … preposterous, I know, but if the manufacturers don't get the target groups right, what can I do

Answer (score 5):

May sound strange but a little bit of spit on the inside of you glasses will stop them from fogging, divers use this to keep there masks from fogging. Also there are different products like [this spray](http://www.proswimwear.co.uk/swimming-goggles/anti-fog-spray.html). But spit works just fine.

Answer (score 3):

Leader brand screen wipes. (Amazon) Or , wipe liquid soap on inside of goggles. wait 10-12 min. clean. These are two ways hockey players keep visors fog/scratch free. Not sure, google No-Fog.  spray for clear plastics

Answer (score 2):

Get hold of an oxygen mask or similar, and attach rubber sheet to act as an "in-only" check valve on the exhaust vents.  Connect a piece of tubing to the oxygen inlet, and route that tube down your neck and into your coat.  Your exhalations will go in a location that won't fog your glasses.

Comment: have you considered how much space the oxygen mask will take inside the mask? how uncomfortable it can be? the reduced amount of air you can breathe?

Answer (score 2):

Wipe your glasses with shaving cream wipe clean. I just did this after days of my eyes being in the fog. works great

Answer (score 1):

Consider a different type of mask, one that leaves your mouth and nose uncovered and thus won't channel your moist breath onto your cold lenses.  Yes, it'll let your face get a little colder, but that's the trade off here.

Comment: Then what's the point of having a mask in the first place? :)

Comment: not to mention it wouldn't even be a mask @DVK

Answer (score 1):

You can buy special anti-fog lenses for your glasses. JINS offer them for people who wear marks and they cost about ５０００円 extra. JINS are also sold in some other countries including China and the US.